# Play sound when app is in background or screen is locked

Tags: objective-c

I have a timer that plays a sound when time reaches 0, but now I can't understand how to fire the event in order to play the sound if the app is in background mode or the screen is locked, What I found searching on the web was to set "`UIBackgroundModes`" in my .plist file, and add "`audio`" as array member.

```
UIBackgroundModes Array
Item0 String audio
```

Then add in the app delegate the following code:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

But the sound doesn't get played.. So I was wondering if it's possible to do something like this or I should change method

**EDIT:**

I imported:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

And this is the code I use to create the sound:

```
AVAudioPlayer *player;
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/clock.mp3",
                               [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL
                                                                   error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = -1;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [player prepareToPlay];
    });
```

Then to play it:

```
[player play];
```

Comment: And the code which plays the sound, how it looks? Have you import MediaPlayer Framework?

Comment: yeah sorry forgot about that :P edited my question, That is the code I use to play the sound and it works fine when app is running but if the app goes in background or screen is locked doesn't get played

Answer (score 1):

I have just a snippet of Swift code but it should be easy to convert it to Obj-C

Try to use `AVPlayerItem init with URL` and then set `AVPlayer init with PlayerItem`

```
let assetUrl = self.nowPlayingItem!.associatedItem!.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! NSURL
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: assetUrl)

if let player = self.player {
    player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(playerItem)
} else {
    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
}
self.player!.play()
```

and for this line of code:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/clock.mp3",
                               [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
```

Have you tried:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"song" withExtension:@"mp3"];
```

Comment: i'm don't know much of swift but i'll try to convert it :P ty

Answer (score -1):

```
// Create a new player item
    NSURL *assetUrl = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:assetUrl];

    // Either create a player or replace it
    if (self.player) {
        [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    } else {
        self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    }
```

nowPlayingItem is here a MPMediaItem but just replace `NSURL *assetUrl = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];` by `NSURL *assetUrl =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"song" withExtension:@"mp3"];`